# Deploy app with several language settings

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-phone-8, marketplace

I want to deploy my [Windows Phone 8 App](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) in the [Dev Center](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/AppSubmission/Hub).
In [Visual Studio 1012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) I can setup the language to "English" as Default and Hook "English" and "German" as supported languages.

Problem is, when uploading to the Marketplace in Dev Center, I am not able to switch to both language description panels to setup each Title+Description+Screenshots. In that case it fails with error, it is missing "German" description, Icon and Screenshots.

How to work with several languages in Dev Center?

[image: Dev Center Upload]

Error:
[image: Dev Center Error]

Answer (score 0):

You should have a ComboBox to select the language in the page you set the description (i.e. the first image of your post):

[image]